# how jQuery implements []

Tags: jquery

```
var p = $("<p>1111111</p><p>1111111</p>");
var _p = p[0]
```

as we know ,when we execute p[0] we get a raw js dom object. is [] a buildin operator or anything else?

how to have my own Object support [] operator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same result by manually assigning items by indices, it is possible with JavaScript.
This way, you will have both custom object members / properties and indexed values.

```js
var $ = function(selector) {
  function ctor(items) {
    this.count = function() {
      return items.length;
    };
    
    this.get = function(ind) {
      return items[ind];
    };

    this.log = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        console.log("Item " + i + ": " + items[i].outerHTML);
    };
 
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      this[i] = items[i];
  }
  
  var items = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  return new ctor(items);
};

var $divs = $("div");
console.log("Count = " + $divs.count());
console.log($divs[0].innerText);
console.log($divs.get(1).innerText);
$divs.log();
```

```html
<div id="div1">1</div>
<div id="div2">2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your wise advise,
$divs[0] is another notion for $divs.0 ,here 0 is just a properties of $divs am i right?

Comment: @rex exactly, idea is right, with one remark - `$divs.0` is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

`[]`  represents an array, not specially bounded to Jquery. When you use Jquery selector, it returns the set of matched elements as an array (almost equals to native array). And the zero you showing is an array index which means getting the first matched element.

Comment: JQuery's selectors don't return an array. They return an array-like JQuery object.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes, the object is iterable and alomst equals to the native array.